# How can I prove that $aN\cap bN=cN$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

Is there any general method for showing that $a\mathbb{N}\cap b\mathbb{N}=c\mathbb{N}$ in set builder form? It can be done by showing that $a\mathbb{N} \cap b\mathbb{N}\subset c\mathbb{N}$ and $c\mathbb{N} \subset a\mathbb{N} \cap b\mathbb{N}$, which will prove that $a\mathbb{N}\cap b\mathbb{N}=c\mathbb{N}$, but the question goes like this, for instance, what is $3\mathbb{N}\cap7\mathbb{N}=?$, the answer is known here, that it is $21\mathbb{N}$ but what will be the method to do that if $a\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $a\mathbb{N}=\{ax:x\in\mathbb{N}\}$?

Comment: Do you know what $c$ is in terms of $a$ and $b$? Once you understand that, it's relatively straightforward to prove that the intersection of $a\mathbb{N}$ and $b\mathbb{N}$ has the form $c\mathbb{N}$ for the appropriate $c$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki what will be c in terms of a and b?

Comment: @MananArora Try a few examples and you should see the pattern.  Don't restrict yourself to $a, b$ prime.  Include $4, 6$ in your tests, for example.

Comment: keyword: *lowest common multiple*

Comment: @janmarqz Thanks! I got that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b\in \Bbb N$ and let $c=lcm (a,b).$

(1). Now $c/a,c/b\in \Bbb N,$  so for any $x$ we have $$x\in c\Bbb N \implies [\,x/a\in (c/a)\Bbb N\subset \Bbb N \,\land \,x/b\in (c/b)\Bbb N\subset \Bbb N\,]\implies$$ $$\implies [\,x/a\in \Bbb N\land x/b\in \Bbb N\,]\implies$$ $$\implies [\,x=(x/a)\cdot a\in a\Bbb N \land x=(x/b)\cdot b\in b\Bbb N\,]\implies$$ $$\implies [x\in a\Bbb N\land x\in b\Bbb N\,]\implies$$ $$\implies x\in a\Bbb N\cap b\Bbb N.$$

(2). We need to know that $\gcd (c/a,c/b)=1$  and hence that if $n\in \Bbb N$ and $(c/b) |(c/a)n$ then $(c/b)|n.\;$(see Appendix).

Now $c/a,c/b\in \Bbb N,$  so for any $x$ we have $$x\in a\Bbb N\cap b\Bbb N\implies\exists m,n \in \Bbb N(x=am=bn)\implies$$ $$\implies x(c/ab)=(c/b)m=(c/a)n\in \Bbb N\implies$$ $$\implies (c/b)|(c/a)n\implies (c/b)|n\implies $$ $$\implies bn/c=n/(c/b)\in \Bbb N\implies  x=bn=(bn/c)c\in c\Bbb N.$$ I have deleted the "$\exists m,n \in \Bbb N$" from the last 3 lines above for easier reading.

Appendix. By definition of $c=lcm (a,b)$ we have $c=\min (a\Bbb N\cap b\Bbb N).$ If $p\in \Bbb N$ and $p$ divides both of $c/a, c/b$ then we have $$[\,(c/a)/p\in \Bbb N\land (c/b)p\in \Bbb N \,] \implies$$ $$\implies [(c/p)=a\cdot (c/a)/p\in a\Bbb N\land (c/p)=b\cdot (c/b)/p\in b\Bbb N ]\implies$$ $$\implies (c/p)\in a\Bbb N\cap b\Bbb N\implies $$ $$\implies(c/p)\ge\min (a\Bbb N\cap b\Bbb N)=c\implies$$ $$ \implies (c/p)\ge c\implies 1\ge p.$$ So $\gcd (c/a,c/b)=1 .$

It is a fundamental theorem that if $u,v,n\in \Bbb N$ with $\gcd (u,v)=1$ and $u|vn$ then $u|n.$ In particular for this Q, when $u=(c/b)$ and $v=(c/a).$

Comment: I find it irritating that \gcd is a thing in MathJax / LaTex but \lcm is not.